Numerical Optimization (Nocedal and Wright) Exercise 11.9
I was doing some of the exercises out of Numerical Optimization by Nocedal and Wright and got stuck on exercise 11.9. The problem is concerned with applying a trust-region version of Newton's method to nonlinear equations. The statement is as follows:

Suppose we replace the assumption of $x_k \rightarrow x^\ast$ in Theorem 11.8 by an assumption that the nondegenerate solution $x^\ast$ is a limit point of $x_k$. Show that $x^\ast$ is the only possible limit point of this sequence. Hint: show that $\lVert J_{k+1}^{-1} r_{k+1} \rVert \leq (1/2)\lVert J_k^{-1} r_k \rVert$ for all $k$ sufficiently large.

For some context, we are solving a general nonlinear system $r(x) = 0$ and $J(x)$ is the Jacobian of $r$ (here $J_k$ is shorthand for $J(x_k)$ and similar for $r_k$). Theorem 11.8 states that, assuming $\{x_k\}$ is the sequence of iterates of a trust-region Newton method, $x_k \rightarrow x^\ast$, a nondegenerate solution of the system of equations, $J(x)$ is Lipschitz continuous on an open neighborhood of $x^\ast$, and the trust-region subproblem is solved exactly for all sufficiently large $k$, then $x_k \rightarrow x^\ast$ quadratically.
I'm not sure how to establish the result in the hint. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
My Thoughts So Far
The hint seems to be implying that we should first show that the Newton step is decreasing linearly in norm. I was thinking then that we could split into cases.

If, at a given iteration we take the Newton step (i.e., the Newton step is within the trust-region radius) we then have quadratic local convergence if we are sufficiently close to $x^\ast$. This implies that the magnitude of the Newton step is decreasing faster than the required bound.
Otherwise, we don't take the Newton step, (i.e., $\lVert p_k \rVert = \Delta_k \leq \lVert J_k^{-1} r_k \rVert$, where $\Delta_k$ is the trust-region radius at step $k$). The proof of Theorem 11.8 shows that if we are sufficiently close then we have some potentially useful bounds (e.g., $\lVert J_k^{-1} \rVert \leq \beta^\ast$ and the actual-to-predicted reduction $\rho_k$ is arbitrarily close to unity). Because $\rho_k$ is close to unity, the trust-region radius will be updated via $\Delta_{k+1} = \min(2 \Delta_k, \hat \Delta)$, where $\hat \Delta$ is some maximum trust-region radius constant. However, I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

